# instantiating Stage with viewport messes up how game looks

Tags: libgdx, viewport

I am building a 3D scene. Up until now, I didn't needed any Viewport. Now I am adding Scene2D UI elements and I need a Viewport instance, because constructor for Stage accepts viewport instance as in  `new Stage(viewport);`

The camera is instantiated in the following way:
`camera=new PerspectiveCamera(45, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());`

```
viewport=new ExtendViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight(),camera);
```

However, once I set a viewport my scene becomes completely messed up. The camera changes position a lot and none of my objects are visible. The default viewport(before I added my own) was perfect and my 3D scene was looking pretty neat. I would like to preserve that behaviour. I want my scene to look exactly as it did before I added a viewport. So the question is... to what must I instantiate a viewport to get it act as if there isn't any?

EDIT: Moreover, the code that messes things up is `stage = new Stage(viewport);` in show method. If I remove this, the 3D scene is fine, if I add it back..all objects are at strange positions.

Answer (score 0):

To switch between viewports you have to call `viewport.apply();` in between using them, as explained [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports#multiple-viewports). If you dont want to use a specific viewport you can call `Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());` to reset it to the entire screen. So, in your render method:

```
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
modelbatch.begin(camera);
// render using modelbatch
modelbatch.end();
stage.getViewport().apply();
stage.draw();
```

Comment: hm. not getting the result I wanted. In mean time  I switched to ScreenViewport, and now the camera is back in place and renders the scene as it were before when no viewport was included. Cant explain why it works, but it works.